# Querying Delta Lake from Inside of UDF in Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

Need to perform some queries to a table inside of a UDF in structured streaming. The problem is, inside the UDF if i try to use **spark.sql**, i am getting null pointer exception. What is the best way to follow here.

Basically i need to stream from a table, and then use that data to perform some range queries from another table.

Eg.

```
val appleFilter = udf((appleId : String) => {
     val query = "select count(*) from appleMart where appleId='"+appleId+"'"
     val appleCount = spark.sql(query).collect().head.getLong(0)
     (appleCount>0)
})

val newApple = apples.filter(appleFilter($"appleId"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a correct approach for this task - you shouldn't do separate queries from inside UDF, as Spark won't be able to parallelize/optimize them.

The better way will be just to do a [join](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-dataframe-join/) between your streaming dataframe & `appleMart` dataframe - this will allow Spark to optimize all operations.  As I understand from your code, you just need to check that you have apples with given ID.  In this case, you can just do the inner join - this will leave only IDs for which there are rows in the `appleMart`, something like this:

```scala
val appleMart = spark.read.format("delta").load("path_to_delta")
val newApple = apples.join(appleMart, apples("appleId") === appleMart("appleId"))
```

if for some reason you need to leave `apples` entries that doesn't exist in the `appleMart`, you can use `left` join instead...

P.S. If `appleMart` doesn't change very often, you can cache it.  Although, for streaming jobs, for lookup tables something like [Cassandra could be better from performance standpoint](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2020/07/spark-effective-joins-with-cassandra.html).