# Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a function in Azure databricks. I would like to spark.sql inside the function. But it looks like I cannot use it with worker nodes.

```
def SEL_ID(value, index):
    # some processing on value here
    ans = spark.sql("SELECT id FROM table WHERE bin = index")
    return ans
spark.udf.register("SEL_ID", SEL_ID)
```

I am getting the following error:
`PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.`

Is there any way I can overcome this? I am using the above function to select from another table.

Comment: I think you are trying to do a [`join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join) (with extra steps)

Comment: cannot do this with an UDF

Comment: @Steven yes, that's the alternative. but I want to avoid it as i have to create a table for that.

Comment: @dtr Why do you need to create a table ? A `join` is between two dataframes. The one your apply your UDF to, and another one create from the table `table` from your sql query. There is probably something you're missing because you are trying to do something complex for a trivial task.

Comment: Please display what you have as input and what you expect as output with sample data.

Comment: It looks very similar to following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147904/querying-delta-lake-from-inside-of-udf-in-databricks/63171653#63171653 - I double on @Steven about join