# how to call function inside function and registering it in spark, Got error as PicklingError see SPARK-5063

Tags: sql, pyspark, azure-databricks

i'm trying to create a udf which contains other function, then i'm registering the function in spark to use that in select query. I need to pass the df(temp table) values as input to the function which is registered.
When tried executing the function getting error as follows

Error: **PicklingError**: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063

```
def funcmain(a,b,c,lvl,x):
   lvl1=lvl
   x1=x
   while lvl1!=lv1:
      x1=x
   if x1!= something:
      x1= something
      func1(a,b,c)
   return x1
udf_fun = spark.register.udf("funcmain",funcmain)
```

Comment: show the code of func1

Comment: thanks Alex for your reply. Function code have same function called twice i'm handling the function call for multiple times call. code follows
def func1(a,b,c,i):
    if c= something:
        then do something
    if c= something:
        then do ..
        func1(a,b,c,i) --handled function call multiple times by passing i value
    if c= something
       then do ....
       spark.sql("select * from test")
       --need to pass select values as intput values to same function
       --used pandas df for calling function

Comment: you can't use `spark` from inside the UDF... if you need to query the data, do the join with that dataset

Comment: thanks Alex for your reply. can you please share me one example?

Comment: for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147904/querying-delta-lake-from-inside-of-udf-in-databricks/63171653#63171653