# Spark UDF not returning correct output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I am using Databricks + Spark 3

```
object obj1 extends Serializable {
    def getAmount (p1: Long, p2: Double, p3: Double): Double = {
        val udmDataDf = sqlContext.sql(s"""select * from table where col = p1""")
        val amount = 100
        
        return amount
      }
}
```

If I run the following command I am getting the value as 100:

```
obj1.getAmount(123456, 100, 100)
output: 100
```

I am creating a UDF and to handle null output I am using Try/Option:

```
import scala.util.Try
val amtUdf = udf((p1: Long, p2: Double, p3: Double) => Try(obj1.getAmount(p1, p2, p3)).toOption)
```

I am adding a column to the dataframe for the calculated value from the function.

The following command runs successfully:

```
val df = df1.withColumn("Amt", amtUdf($"p1", $"p2", $"p3"))
```

But when I try to check the data using the below, Amt column is coming null:

```
df.show
```

If I delete the following line from the function getAmount then the above command gives the output 100:

```
val udmDataDf = sqlContext.sql(s"""select * from table where col = p1""")
```

how can I fix the UDF to get the correct output.

Comment: You cannot call Spark SQL inside a UDF. What you're trying to do looks like a join. UDF is not needed.

Comment: I've seen multiple questions like this (for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63147904/querying-delta-lake-from-inside-of-udf-in-databricks/63171653#63171653). It's definitely join...

Comment: thanks for the comments! I have just mentioned 1 function...actual code contain many functions which would involve many calculations and contains dataframe...